# Connect to process running Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

I have a Rails console running in a process on my server (`bundle exec rails c`) and I'd like to be able to SSH into that server and "connect" to that process, as if I had started the Rails console myself.

Is that possible?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution like running the console in [screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) so that you can attach and detach from it? If not, can you clarify how exactly you're picturing the solution working from a user's perspective? Also, why the requirement for only having one process running?

Comment: Brilliant, why didn't I think of `screen`?! :) I will go with `tmux` instead, but if course this is the right way...

Comment: To explain a bit more: I'd like to have an easy and quick way to access the Rails console in production, and not having to start it from scratch each time. I just switched from self-hosted to Render.com with our app, and they provide you with a start command for each app instance, so I'm trying to set up a separate app instance that simply starts the console and automatically redeploys (like the web app instance) on each Git push.

Comment: @ManuelMeurer you can use SSH to connect to your Rails app running on Render: https://render.com/docs/ssh

Comment: Thanks, @anurag! I'm doing that, but I want the Rails console to already be running once I connect. :) Starting it with tmux during a deploy and then connecting via SSH and reattaching works great! You're building a fantastic product with Render.com, it's been a revelation after more than a decade on Heroku. Keep it up!

Comment: That's a great hack! Are you moving apps over from Heroku or starting a new one?

Comment: Currently I'm moving over an app hosted on DO droplets, but I have a few on Heroku that I plan to tackle next! :)